# Write in DB doesn't work in Controller, but works in view - Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm trying to write some data in a DB after clicking on a save button.

During my development I was writing successfully in my DB with PHP code in my view, but the PHP code was ran when the page was loaded and not when my button was clicked.

What I did is a redirection to an address that call a function in my controller and then, that redirect to a login page.

Here is my controller's code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use JavaScript;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class bus_confirmationController extends Controller{
    public function test(){

        $results = DB::select('select bus_direction from bus_line where card_uid = "0xcb009299"', array(1));
        JavaScript::put([
            'selectionData' => $results
        ]);

        return view('bus_confirmation');
    }

    public function postRequest(){

        DB::table('bus_line')->insert(
            array('ID' => '', 'bus_direction' => '77t', 'card_uid' => '0xcb009299')
        );
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Here is my view's code:

```
[...]
<div class="panel panel-default" id="save" onclick="savedata()" >
    SAVE
</div>
[...]


<script type="text/javascript">
function savedata() {
        var toReturn = [];
        var data = ["88t", "85t","77t","redLinet"];
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var image = document.getElementById(data[i]).style.visibility;
            if (image==="visible" || image===""){
                toReturn.push([data[i], "visible"]);
            }
        }
        window.location = 'Bus_confirmationSend';

        //Where I used to do my request to write my data 
        /*DB::table('bus_line')->insert(
            array('ID' => '', 'bus_direction' => '88t', 'card_uid' => '0xcb009299')

        );*/

        console.log(toReturn);
    }
</script>
```

Here is what's inside web.php

```
Route::get('/bus_confirmationSend', 'bus_confirmationController@postRequest');
```

I know my connexion to my database is working as the function 'test' from the controller works, I can retrieve data from my DB. I also know that my first redirection to 'bus_directionController' works as the second redirection to 'home' works.

Am I missing something? I really don't understand what can be wrong here.

Comment: it may be because you have `window.location = 'Bus_confirmationSend';` but your route starts with lower case b

Comment: @HH You're right... Sometime mistakes are so simple... Thanks for pointing that out. Make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you have `window.location = 'Bus_confirmationSend';` but your route starts with lower case b